# How to prevent the first character to be a number

Tags: c#

I have a textbox control and allowing the user to enter only letters or numbers:

```
private void tbTableName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbTableName.Text = string.Concat(tbTableName.Text.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
            if (tbTableName.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                btnConvert.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                btnConvert.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

How can I modify so that the first character cannot be a digit, only letter and then they can add as many digit as they want?

I have a WinForm, not a Web Form.

Comment: What is hard in checking `tbTableName.Text[i]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just remove the first character if it's a number:

```
if (tbTableName.Text.Length > 0 && char.IsNumber(tbTableName.Text[0]))
    tbTableName.Text = tbTableName.Text.Substring(1);
```

Comment: I get Index was outside of the bounds of he array error.

Comment: @SiKni8 - Edited my answer. You'd have to check that `tbTableName` has some text before trying to access any of it's items.

Comment: Not sure why it's a downvote. I Upvoted and will accept it when SO lets me :) Thanks.

Comment: Just accepted your edit too. Removed ToString because it wasn't needed. tbTableName.Text is already a string.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify this line:

```
if (tbTableName.Text.Length > 0)
```

to:

```
if (tbTableName.Text.Length > 0 && !Char.IsDigit(tbTableName.Text[0]))
```

Comment: If the first digit is a digit I want it to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using regular expression?

I edit the regular expression to allow user to add digit or letter after the first digit

`btnConvert.Enabled = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");`

Comment: The user can put letters and numbers ONLY with the exception the first character cannot be a digit... Will that take care of it?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void tbTableName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = Regex.Replace(tbTableName.Text, @"^\d+|\W", string.Empty);
    btnConvert.Enabled = name.Length > 0;
    tbTableName.Text = name;
}
```